# AngularJS - Directives as reusable html components

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, semantics

This is a more architectural question, Let's say I got a component,(for example label and text field and a help tool-tip), the structure is same in lot's of places in my application, but the validation, text, and field to bind is different.

Should I work hard on a flexible directive and re-use it whenever I can. or should i just write the html over and over to keep it very flexible?

What are the guidelines for creating directives?

Answer (score 0):

Very difficult to give a general answer because these sorts of decisions are usually specific to the type of application.  However, as you know, you shouldn't add an abstraction unless it adds value.

So, a directive that wraps up a tool-tip, label and input field could add value by reducing the time it takes to place these on the page.  However, if form validation needs to be done, you need to have a way from outside the directive to control the validation.  As you've stated, this can be where flexibility becomes important.

So, obviously there is a balance to be struck.

The best guidance, therefore, must be to start by not having a directive.  Wait until you see the shape of what can be wrapped up very clearly, and then move to an abstraction that you know will save you time.